# Facebook Connect query about customizing the share-button

Tags: button, facebook, share

I really hate asking about Facebook Connect on SO, but their own development forums are horrendous.

We're implementing a Facebook share button using this:

```
<fb:share-button class="url" href="http://oursite.com/"></fb:shared-button>
```

This is documented(poorly) here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:share-button

I need to be able to change the text from "Share" to something else. I've spent 2 hours looking for an answer to this and have come up short.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible.  You can change it to other facebook defaults though - http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:login-button

Comment: Thank you so much. The answer really was staring me in the face. Just made my own anchor tag with their js call and its perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the replacement like social plugin (the one you should be using now instead of the deprecated fb:share-button), you have two choices for the button text:  `Like` or `Recommend`.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to customize the facebook share button, look at the url you would use for a desktop app.  Makes it much better.  You can also use AddThis the same way to get some analytics from the share.